# AngularJs Gridster Options Issue

Tags: angularjs, gridster

I am using AngularJS Gridster :- https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster

In my controller, I try to initialise some properties :-

```
var app = angular.module('appDashboard', ['gridster', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$modal',
    function ($scope, $timeout, $modal) {

    $scope.gridsterOptions = {
                margins: [20, 20],
                columns: 4,
                draggable: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            };
....
}
```

These Settings do not get apply when gridster is loaded.  When i change these settings directly in the `.js` they get apply.

Any Idea how to get this working?

Comment: Any chance of sharing some of your view? How are you passing those settings to gridster?

Answer (score 0):

Passing the `gridsterOptions` did the thing :-

```
<div gridster="gridsterOptions">
```